# delete database data using grid view button but returns me with null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is how my gridview looks like:

[image]

I need to delete the selected row where there is a hidden column `activityID and taskID` which I set visible to false because I need their value to delete it from the database.
I have to delete from database using `QuestionNo , activityID and taskID` .

`ActivityID and TaskID is hidden` , it actually looks like this :

> QuestionNo,ActivtiyID,TaskID,QuestionContent then delete.

Code :

```
    protected void gvQuestion_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {     


    }

    protected void gvQuestion_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void gvQuestion_RowDeleting1(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        gvQuestion.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);

         Model.question del = new Model.question();

        int q = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ToString());
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].ToString()); // Hidden Column
        int t = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ToString()); // Hidden Column

        del.QuestionNo = q; 
        del.ActivityID = a;// Value of ActivityID column in GV
        del.TaskID = t; // Value of TaskID column in GV


        daoQuestion.Delete(del);
        daoQuestion.Save();
    }`
```

From what i know once delete button is pressed , it fires OnRowDeleting event so i put my delete codes in there , however i connection reset when i try to delete , the values of q , a , t is null , what gone wrong here? , The delete button is not working.. Help please , thanks . i am using EF to do this btw...

Here is the aspx :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestion" runat="server"   
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            onselectedindexchanged="gvQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onrowcommand="gvQuestion_RowCommand" onrowdeleted="gvQuestion_RowDeleted" onrowdeleting="gvQuestion_RowDeleting1" 
             >
             <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionNo" HeaderText="QuestionNo" 
                        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QuestionNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityID" HeaderText="ActivityID" 
                        SortExpression="ActivityID" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="TaskID" 
                        SortExpression="TaskID" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="joined" HeaderText="QuestionContent" 
                        SortExpression="joined" >
                    <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
                                onclick="LinkButton1_Click" CommandArgument="Delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

With data keys ( duno if this is the correct way ) :

aspx :

```
 DataKeyNames="QuestionNo,ActivityID,TaskID"
```

code behind :

```
  protected void gvQuestion_RowDeleting1(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView gvQuestion = (GridView)sender;
        int row = e.RowIndex;

        int q = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.DataKeys[row].Value[0].ToString());
        int a= Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.DataKeys[row].Value[1].ToString());
        int t = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.DataKeys[row].Value[2].ToString()); // I assume that value 0 , 1 , 2 is according to the columns , not really sure on this.


 /*    Model.question del = new Model.question();
        del.QuestionNo = q; 
       del.ActivityID = a;// Value of ActivityID column in GV
        del.TaskID = t; // Value of TaskID column in GV


        daoQuestion.Delete(del);
      daoQuestion.Save();
      gvQuestion.DataBind(); */
    }
```

I am just trying to retrieve the values so i'll comment out the delete codes .. i check the values by debugging and returns 0 . is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I will like to advise to set `QuestionNo,ActivtiyID,TaskID` as DataKey of Gridview. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx) to know how to add multiple `DataKey` to `GridView`. Check How to use `RowDeleting` event of grid view using [DataKey](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/212_How_to_edit_and_Delete_records_in_a_gridview_using_datakeys.aspx). Check [Delete records in Gridview with multi-datakeynames in GridView](http://forums.asp.net/t/1671239.aspx/1). Hope you understand and works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting a row, not selecting it, so selectedindex won't have anything, unless you've selected a row previously. You should use the information in the GridViewDeleteEventArgs. In there you can find the rowindex, as well as the data for columns you've marked as key columns.

Comment: hi there , thanks for the reply . what do u mean by information in gridviewdeleteeventargs? .. and how can i retrieve info from there?

Comment: It's the second parameter in gvQuestion_RowDeleting1. You use it like any variable.

Comment: oh , sorry that i am new , i have updated my codes but i try to delete , the whole connection crashes.

Comment: this that the correct way to delete : 
int q = Convert.ToInt32(gvQuestion.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ToString());  ??
because i need to get the value first before i could delete in database

Comment: the 3 statement returns Null and btw i converted boundfield to template field